# Discretizing PDE using the 9-point Laplacian with variable coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, laplacian

[image: Discretizing PDE using the 9-point Laplacian Problem]

Here are the notes described:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/771c/15fba0308428ae1a2bf8db9c8f8d1b63eb3d.pdf

My Attempt:
[image: My Attempt]

This is what I tried, but then I realized that this would not end with 9-points. I tried to use the centered difference approximation for the points immediately around the center and then again for the points next to those.

[image: Next Attempt]

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: @faith_in_facts Hi, I updated the post to show my attempt, but I know my approach will not work.

Comment: well for one, you are missing a lot of terms as defined in the 9 point laplacian eq 3.17. also did you consider the product rule when taking the derivatives with respect to $a*du$?

Comment: @faith_in_facts Thank you! I updated my next attempt which I think should be good. Does this look correct? Also, is this 4th order since the first two terms are products of 2nd order terms?